# SQLite, select where field 'like' field from another table

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to remove "bad words" from a table using a list of offensive words from another table, but the offensive words are often in lemma form. Thus, I can't always do a exact match. I need to use a LIKE quantifier, for example WHERE text LIKE '%badword%'

Is there a way for me to try to select all the rows that contains a word from another table, but by specifically using the LIKE clause.

I'll give an example of what I was trying to do. This didn't work, but should give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM entry 
WHERE headword LIKE IN
( SELECT word
FROM sies )
```

Now I know that the LIKE doesn't fit into this query, but I'm trying to get something to this effect working.

EDIT:
This is the latest thing I tried, that did not work:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM sies AS s, entry AS e 
WHERE e.headword LIKE ('%' + s.word + '%')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
select s.* from sies s, entry e where s.words like '%' || e.word || '%'
```

Here I have assumed that, `sies` is your regular table and `entry` is the table with the dirty words.

You can check the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f1827/4) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT e.*
  FROM entry  e
  JOIN sies s ON MATCH(e.words) AGAINST (s.words IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Does this work in SQLite3? I tried this, but it's not quite working. It's a very interesting answer though. Thank you for the reply. Much appreciated.