# Is it possible to invert the order of "LIKE" operation?

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

My database has a table with columns `genus`, species, and `inatcode`. `inatcode` is blank for every row it hasn't been manually added to. I imported a new table that contains all the codes and want to create an Update query that copies them all to the corresponding rows of the first table. However, because the species column of my first table has additional strings, the match is not perfect and many rows were not updated. `table.a.species` might look like :

```
x bimundorum
vesicula (sexgen)
sinuata breviloba
```

And I want it to match these values in `table.b.species`:

```
bimundorum
vesicula
sinuata
```

I know to use `table.a.species LIKE '%table.b.species%'` when `b` is a substring of `a`, but this is the opposite case and just flipping (shown below) doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to accomplish this in SQLite? The differences between `a` and `b` are heterogeneous, but there are only a few cases and I could potentially do multiple queries to account for each.

```
    "UPDATE table.a SET inatcode = table.b.inatcode
    FROM table.b
    WHERE table.b.genus = table.a.genus 
    AND table.a.species LIKE '%table.b.species%' "
```

I am working with SQLite through the DBI package in R, and could make all of this happen in R and reinsert instead. But it seems like this I should be able to do in SQLite.

Comment: Apart from the syntactical errors in your code which may be simplified, the logic is correct. What is the problem? Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't update the fields I am hoping to update. It just outputs "0" (as in 0 fields updated) and if I query the associated data it is still blank. I don't know why. I will give the fiddle a shot and let you know. What are the errors in the code?

Comment: @forpas The db-fiddle link you sent isn't working but [I can reproduce it here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgWk3NMmpkryrV1dzbQfHc/1). It works just fine when I set species.species = inatcodes.species but if I go to species.species LIKE '%inatcodes.species%' nothing happens at all. My worry is that I'm screwing up something simple in the formatting and it's just looking for cells that contain the literal string "inatcodes.species" ? But I feel like I've used this formatting before and it's worked so idk

Answer (score 0):

The [modified formatting posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29766435/6062476) does what I wanted; I just needed to use the || to concatenate the values and the % operator to make the LIKE function behave as I wanted it to.

```
 "UPDATE table.a SET inatcode = table.b.inatcode
FROM table.b
WHERE table.b.genus = table.a.genus 
AND table.a.species LIKE '%' || table.b.species || '%' 
AND table.b.species != '' "
```